# Pull list of contacts in MC not currently syncing with SF

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to pull a DE of contacts in MC who at one point were part of the sync with Salesforce (so exist in All Contacts) but are no longer syncing. Assume query but don't know what field would indicate they're no longer syncing?

Answer (score 1):

Start with this article: [Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313920&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

Using the mobile filteredlist concept you could have something similar to emailaddress is null and Salesforce_contact.id is null

or SQL query where you can left join with _subscriber data view and not present in your sync object